# Can jq perform aggregation across files

Tags: json, matlab, csv, elasticsearch, jq

I'm trying to identify a program/software which will allow me to efficiently take a number of large CSV files (totaling 40+ GB) and output a JSON file with the specific format I need for import into Elasticsearch (ES).

Can jq efficiently take data like this:

```
file1:
id,age,gender,wave
1,49,M,1
2,72,F,0

file2:
id,time,event1
1,4/20/2095,V39
1,4/21/2095,T21
2,5/17/2094,V39
```

aggregate it by id (such that all the JSON documents from CSV rows in multiple files fall under a single id entry), outputting something like this:

```
{"index":{"_index":"forum_mat","_type":"subject","_id":"1"}}
{"id":"1","file1":[{"filen":"file1","id":"1","age":"49","gender":"M","wave":"1"}],"file2":[{"filen":"file2","id":"1","time":"4/20/2095","event1":"V39"},{"filen":"file2","id":"1","time":"4/21/2095","event1":"T21"}]}
{"index":{"_index":"forum_mat","_type":"subject","_id":"2"}}
{"id":"2","file1":[{"filen":"file1","id":"2","age":"72","gender":"F","wave":"0"}],"file2":[{"filen":"file2","id":"2","time":"5/17/2094","event1":"V39"}]}
```

I wrote a script in Matlab but as I was worried about it is much to slow.  I might take months to crunch all 40+GB of data.  I was [informed](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/logstash-mutate-filter-rename-exception-in-filterworker-exception-indexerror-string-not-matched/33438/4) that Logstash (which is the preferred data input tool for ES) isn't good at this type of aggregation.

Comment: it may be easier to feed this data into a relational database first, properly structured, referenced and indexed (Ex: http://www.tech-recipes.com/rx/2345/import_csv_file_directly_into_mysql/) then write a query that returns json (Ex https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json.html)

Comment: I ended up using this approach and posted the detailed answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested in one of the comments I ended up using SQL to export JSON in the format I required.  Another [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33662850/formatting-postgres-json-output-for-nested-elasticsearch-structure) helped tremendously.  In the end I choose to output a given SQL table to its own JSON file instead of combining them (the file size was becoming unmanageable).  This is the code structure to do that such that you produce the command line for the Bulk API and the JSON data line:

```
create or replace function format_data_line(command text, data_str text)
returns setof text language plpgsql as $$
begin
    return next command;
    return next             
        replace(
            regexp_replace(data_str,
                '(\d\d\d\d-\d\d-\d\d)T', '\1 ', 'g'),
            e' \n ', '');
end $$;

COPY (
    with f_1 as(
       SELECT id, json_agg(fileX.*) AS tag
       FROM forum.file3
       GROUP BY id
    )
    SELECT 
        format_data_line(
            format('{"update":{"_index":"forum2","_type":"subject","_id":%s}}',a.id),
            format('{"doc":{"id":%s,"fileX":%s}}', 
                a.id, a.tag))
    FROM f_1 a 
) TO '/path/to/json/fileX.json';
```

Importing the larger files with the Bulk API also turned out to be problematic (out of memory Java errors) so a script was needed to only send subsets of the data to Curl (for indexing in Elasticsearch) at a given time.  The basic structure for that script is:

```
#!/bin/bash

FILE=$1
INC=100
numline=`wc -l $FILE | awk '{print $1}'`
rm -f output/$FILE.txt
for i in `seq 1 $INC $numline`; do
    TIME=`date +%H:%M:%S`
    echo "[$TIME] Processing lines from $i to $((i + INC -1))"
    rm -f intermediates/interm_file_$i.json
    sed -n $i,$((i +INC - 1))p $FILE >> intermediates/interm_file_$i.json
    curl -s -XPOST localhost:9200/_bulk --data-binary @intermediates/interm_file_$i.json >> output/$FILE.txt
done
```

An "intermediates" directory should be created beneath the script files directory.  The script can be saved as "ESscript" and run on the command line with:

```
./ESscript fileX.json
```

Answer (score 0):

The following, I believe, does what you said you want, but I don't fully understand the connection between your input files and the output that you included.  Hopefully this will at least put you on the right track.

The program assumes all your data will fit into memory.  It uses JSON objects as dictionaries for fast lookup and so should be quite performant.

The approach taken here separates the csv-to-json conversion from the aggregation, as there may be better ways to do the former.  (See for example [the jq Cookbook entry on convert-a-csv-file-with-headers-to-json](https://github.com/stedolan/jq/wiki/Cookbook#convert-a-csv-file-with-headers-to-json).)

The first file (scsv2json.jq) is for converting simple CSV to JSON.  The second file (aggregate.jq) does the aggregation.  With these in place:

`$ (jq -R -s -f scsv2json.jq file1.csv ;\
   jq -R -s -f scsv2json.jq file2.csv) |\
   jq -s -c -f aggregate.jq
[{"id":"1",
  "file1":{"age":"49","gender":"M","wave":"1"},
  "file2":{"time":"4/21/2095","event1":"T21"}},
 {"id":"2",
   "file1":{"age":"72","gender":"F","wave":"0"},
   "file2":{"time":"5/17/2094","event1":"V39"}}]`

Notice that the "id" has been removed from the inner objects in the output.

aggregate.jq:

```
# Input: an array of objects, each with an "id" field
# such that (tostring|.id) is an index.
# Output: a dictionary keyed by the id field.
def todictionary:
  reduce .[] as $row ( {}; . + { ($row.id | tostring): $row } );

def aggregate:
  .[0] as $file1
  | .[1] as $file2
  | ($file1 | todictionary) as $d1
  | ($file2 | todictionary) as $d2
  | ( [$file1[].id] + [$file2[].id] | unique ) as $keys
  | reduce ($keys[] | tostring) as $k
      ( [];
        . + [{"id": $k, 
              "file1": ($d1[$k] | del(.id)),
              "file2": ($d2[$k] | del(.id)) }] );

aggregate
```

scsv2json.jq

```
def objectify(headers):
  . as $in
  | reduce range(0; headers|length) as $i
      ({}; .[headers[$i]] = ($in[$i]) );

def csv2table:
  def trim: sub("^ +";"") |  sub(" +$";"");
  split("\n") | map( split(",") | map(trim) );

def csv2json:
  csv2table
  | .[0] as $headers
  | reduce (.[1:][] | select(length > 0) ) as $row
      ( []; . + [ $row|objectify($headers) ]);

csv2json
```

The above assumes that a version of jq with regex support is being used.  If your jq does not have regex support, simply omit the trimming.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try to get this running on my larger dataset. Regarding the data fitting into memory, I assume this doesn't have to be physical RAM (it can be virtual also)?  Regarding the first line of my output, I need a line like this for each id to tell Elasticsearch to index the data: `{"index":{"_index":"forum_mat","_type":"subject","_id":"1"}}`. The _index, _type aren't dynamic but it would be nice if the _id matched the actual id.  I assume that after getting comfortable with jq I should be able to figure out how to quickly enter these command lines between the actual data lines?

Comment: Making up your own "csv2json" function is almost surely a bad idea. The CSV standard is not as simple as it looks, and CSVs found in the wild often deviate from the standard in subtle ways. Luckily, [`csvkit`](http://csvkit.readthedocs.org/en/0.9.1/) includes a `csvjson` application that does exactly this.

Comment: I am able run this on my simple dataset above.  I can also convert my data to json first using `csvjson` from csvkit and then use this command: `jq -s -c -f aggregate.jq file1_csvkit.json file2_csvkit.json`.  However in both cases it will only keep the last line for a given id from a given file.  For example the `1,4/20/2095,V39` row from my example data gets dropped in the output: `jq -s -c -f aggregate.jq file1_csvkit.json file2_csvkit.json`
`[{"id":"1","file1":{"AGE":"49","GENDER":"M","WAVE":"1"},"file2":{"TIME":"4/21/2095","EVENT1":"T21"}}`

Answer (score 0):

Here is a less memory-intensive approach.  It only requires that file1
be kept in memory: the second file is processed one line at a time.

Invocation is like so:

```
$ jq -n -R --argfile file1 <(jq -R -s -f scsv2json.jq file1.csv)\
     -f aggregate.jq file2.csv
```

where scsv2json.jq is as shown in the previous post. It is not repeated here mainly because (as pointed out elsewhere) some other program for converting CSV to JSON in the same manner may be appropriate.

aggregate.jq:

```
def objectify(headers):
  . as $in
  | reduce range(0; headers|length) as $i
      ({}; .[headers[$i]] = ($in[$i]) );

def csv2table:
  def trim: sub("^ +";"") |  sub(" +$";"");
  split("\n") | map( split(",") | map(trim) );

# Input: an array of objects, each with an "id" field
# such that (tostring|.id) is an index.
# Output: a dictionary keyed by the id field.
def todictionary:
  reduce .[] as $row ( {}; . + { ($row.id | tostring): $row } );

# input: {"id": ID } + OBJECT2
# dict: {ID: OBJECT1, ...}
# output: {id: ID, "file1": OBJECT1, "file2": OBJECT2}
def aggregate(dict):
  .id as $id
  | (dict[$id] | del(.id)) as $o1
  | {"id": $id,
     "file1": $o1,
     "file2":  del(.id) };

# $file1 is the JSON version of file1.csv -- an array of objects
(input | csv2table[0]) as $headers
| inputs
| csv2table[0]
| objectify($headers) 
| ($file1 | todictionary) as $d1
| aggregate($d1)
```

Comment: Great, thanks again!  When I run this improved aggregation code (renaming it to aggregaten) on the example data I get this error: `jq -n -R --argfile file1 <(jq -R -s -f scsv2json.jq file1.csv)\ -f aggregaten.jq file2.csv` 
`C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\lib\jq\tools\jq.exe: Bad JSON in --argfile file1 /dev/fd/63 -f: Could not open /dev/fd/63 -f: No such file or directory Error: writing output failed: Invalid argument`

Comment: The example invocation here assumes bash.  For Windows, it would probably be simplest to create a temporary file. It may, however, be a better use of your time to focus on the approach that does a "global sort" first.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an approach for which the jq memory requirements are trivially small.  It assumes that you've been able to merge all your .csv files into one stream (or file) of JSON arrays of the form:

```
[id, sourceFile, baggage]
```

where the value of id is in sorted order.  The stream might look like this:

```
 [1,"file1", {"a":1}]
 [1,"file2", {"b":1}]
 [1,"file3", {"c":1}]
 [2,"file1", {"d":1}]
 [2,"file2", {"e":1}]
 [3,"file1", {"f":1}]
```

This preliminary step requires a global sort and thus you may need to select a sort utility carefully.

There can be as many file sources as you like; there is no need for each array to fit on one line; and the id values need not be integers -- they could, for example, be strings instead.

Let's assume the above is in a file named combined.json and that aggregate.jq has the contents shown below.  Then the invocation:

```
$ jq -c -n -f aggregate.jq combined.json
```

would produce:

```
{"id":1,"file1":{"a":1},"file2":{"b":1},"file3":{"c":1}}
{"id":2,"file1":{"d":1},"file2":{"e":1}}
{"id":3,"file1":{"f":1}}
```

CORRECTED: aggregate.jq:

```
foreach (inputs,null) as $row
  # At each iteration, if .emit then emit it
  ( {"emit": null, "current": null};

    if $row == null
    then {emit: .current, current: null}          # signal EOF
    else  {id: $row[0], ($row[1]) : $row[2] } as $this
    | if .current == null
      then {emit: null, current: $this}
      elif $row[0] == .current.id
      then .emit = null | .current += $this
      else {emit: .current, current: $this}
      end
    end;
    if .emit then .emit else empty end
  )
```

Comment: Thanks once again!  I can run your example.  As you indicate in your output for some reason the first line is repeated but otherwise it seems like this should work.  I've been trying to familiarize myself with jq enough to simply create: `[1,"file1", {"a":1, "b":3}] [2,"file1", {"a":2,"b":5}]` for a single file but this syntax is very foreign to me so I'm not having much luck.  Could you provide some suggestions?  I'm also hoping to look into directly exporting from SQL to JSON soon since I'm more comfortable with that syntax.

Comment: aggregate,jq has been corrected.  Sorry for the rushed version.