# Formatting Postgres JSON output for nested Elasticsearch structure

Tags: sql, json, postgresql, elasticsearch

I've come to realize that using a SQL database (Postgres) is one of the most efficient ways to port my relational data (40+ GB across 24 CSV files) into Elasticsearch with a [nested structure](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/nested-mapping.html).  However I'm still having a couple issues with the formatting of my JSON output from Postgres: 1) undesired line feeds (\n), 2) undesired header line and 3) undesired date format.  Here is a basic example to demonstrate:

```
file1
id,age,gender,wave
1,49,M,1
2,72,F,0

file2
id,time,event1
1,2095-04-20 12:28:55,V39
1,2095-04-21 2:27:45,T21
2,2094-05-17 18:17:25,V39

file3
id,time,event2
1,2095-04-22 3:48:53,P90
2,2094-05-18 1:28:23,RT4
2,2094-05-18 4:23:53,W3
```

after adding these CSVs to a schema named forum and running this SQL code:

```
with f_1 as(
   SELECT id, json_agg(file1.*) AS tag
   FROM forum.file1
   GROUP BY id
), f_2 as (
   SELECT id, json_agg(file2.*) AS tag
   FROM forum.file2
   GROUP BY id
), f_3 as (
   SELECT id, json_agg(file3.*) AS tag
   FROM forum.file3
   GROUP BY id
)
SELECT ('{"id":' || a.id), ('"file1":' || a.tag), ('"file2":' || b.tag), ('"file3":' || c.tag ||'}') 
FROM f_1 AS a, f_2 AS b, f_3 AS c
WHERE b.id = a.id AND c.id = a.id;
```

I get this output (pgAdminIII - Export to file - no quoting):

```
?column?,?column?,?column?,?column?
{"id":1,"file1":[{"id":1,"age":49,"gender":"M","wave":1}],"file2":[{"id":1,"time":"2095-04-20T12:28:55","event1":"V39"}, 
 {"id":1,"time":"2095-04-21T02:27:45","event1":"T21"}],"file3":[{"id":1,"time":"2095-04-22T03:48:53","event2":"P90"}]}
{"id":2,"file1":[{"id":2,"age":72,"gender":"F","wave":0}],"file2":[{"id":2,"time":"2094-05-17T18:17:25","event1":"V39"}],"file3":[{"id":2,"time":"2094-05-18T01:28:23","event2":"RT4"}, 
 {"id":2,"time":"2094-05-18T04:23:53","event2":"W3"}]}
```

You can see that for a given id there is data on multiple lines.  I need all of the data to be on one line for a given id (i.e. no \n's).  A couple other minor issues which I haven't spent much time on but would like to change are the first row isn't needed, I'd like to get rid of the `?column?,?column?,?column?,?column?` without having to open the file after it's done processing.  Ideally I'd also prefer that there was no `T` in the date output.  I should be able to accommodate the `T` in Elasticsearch but thus far haven't gotten it to accept it.  This is the output I desire from Postgres which works for input into Elasticsearch (using [stream2es](https://github.com/elastic/stream2es) and a nested mapping structure):

```
{"id":1,"file1":[{"id":1,"age":49,"gender":"M","wave":1}],"file2":[{"id":1,"time":"2095-04-20 12:28:55","event1":"V39"},{"id":1,"time":"2095-04-21 02:27:45","event1":"T21"}],"file3":[{"id":1,"time":"2095-04-22 03:48:53","event2":"P90"}]}
{"id":2,"file1":[{"id":2,"age":72,"gender":"F","wave":0}],"file2":[{"id":2,"time":"2094-05-17 18:17:25","event1":"V39"}],"file3":[{"id":2,"time":"2094-05-18 01:28:23","event2":"RT4"},{"id":2,"time":"2094-05-18 04:23:53","event2":"W3"}]}
```

Adding `to_json` does fix the undesired line feeds but it adds `\"` in place of `"` which the stream2es parser doesn't like:

`SELECT to_json('{"id":' || a.id), to_json('"file1":' || a.tag::json), to_json('"file2":' || b.tag::json), to_json('"file3":' || c.tag::json ||'}')`

`"{\"id\":1","\"file1\":[{\"id\":1,\"age\":49,\"gender\":\"M\",\"wave\":1}]"`...

es2stream exception:
`Exception in thread "stream dispatcher" java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to clojure.lang.IPersistentMap`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select all in one column (instead of four). The function [format()](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/functions-string.html#FUNCTIONS-STRING-FORMAT) will help you to write it down more clearly. Use

```
regexp_replace (str, '(\d\d\d\d-\d\d-\d\d)T', '\1 ', 'g')
```

to correct the date format and

```
replace (str, e' \n ', '')
```

to skip newline chars.

Use [COPY command](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/sql-copy.html) to simplify the issue:

```
COPY (
    with f_1 as(
       SELECT id, json_agg(file1.*) AS tag
       FROM forum.file1
       GROUP BY id
    ), f_2 as (
       SELECT id, json_agg(file2.*) AS tag
       FROM forum.file2
       GROUP BY id
    ), f_3 as (
       SELECT id, json_agg(file3.*) AS tag
       FROM forum.file3
       GROUP BY id
    )
    SELECT
        replace(
            regexp_replace(
                format('{"id":%s,"file1":%s,"file2":%s,"file3":%s}', 
                    a.id, a.tag, b.tag, c.tag),
                '(\d\d\d\d-\d\d-\d\d)T', '\1 ', 'g'),
            e' \n ', '')
    FROM f_1 AS a, f_2 AS b, f_3 AS c
    WHERE b.id = a.id AND c.id = a.id
) TO '/full/path/to/your/file';
```

---

To prepend each line of data with a command line you can use a trick with a function returning two rows.
Some part of formatting can be moved to the function on the occasion.

```
create or replace function format_data_line(command text, data_str text)
returns setof text language plpgsql as $$
begin
    return next command;
    return next             
        replace(
            regexp_replace(data_str,
                '(\d\d\d\d-\d\d-\d\d)T', '\1 ', 'g'),
            e' \n ', '');
end $$;

COPY (
    with f_1 as(
       SELECT id, json_agg(file1.*) AS tag
       FROM forum.file1
       GROUP BY id
    ), f_2 as (
       SELECT id, json_agg(file2.*) AS tag
       FROM forum.file2
       GROUP BY id
    ), f_3 as (
       SELECT id, json_agg(file3.*) AS tag
       FROM forum.file3
       GROUP BY id
    )
    SELECT 
        format_data_line(
            'my command', 
            format('{"id":%s,"file1":%s,"file2":%s,"file3":%s}', 
                a.id, a.tag, b.tag, c.tag))
    FROM f_1 AS a, f_2 AS b, f_3 AS c
    WHERE b.id = a.id AND c.id = a.id
) TO '/full/path/to/your/file';
```

Comment: This seems to be doing exactly what I asked for, thanks!  However stream2es seems to be breaking when I feed in a large file.  Therefore I'm planning to go back to using the [Bulk API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-bulk.html).  For that I need to add a command line ({command}\n) above each data line.  I've been trying to figure out how to add line breaks to the above but haven't had any luck (E'\n' and `standard_conforming_strings` formatting are entering \n's as actual strings which aren't being recognized as line feeds).

Comment: Thanks again! Unfortunately my example didn't include the case when a given subject might be missing from a file.  Using the structure above this will eliminate them because of the `AND`'s).  I figured out how to use `LEFT OUTER JOIN` instead of `WHERE` to alleviate this but the leftover string from the format statement is an issue.  For example if you eliminate the two lines for 'id 1' from file2.csv the output will give `"file2":,"file3":[{"id":1,` which isn't valid.  I've tried forcing"file2":{},"file3" in the case of NULL but can't get it to work with CASE or COALESE.

Comment: Also I should note that I added a format line since I wanted the id to be dynamic in my command line of code: `format('{"index":{"_index":"forum_sql_bulk","_type":"subject","_id":%s}}',a.id),
            format('{"id":%s,"file1":%s,"file2":%s,"file3":%s}', 
                a.id, a.tag, b.tag, c.tag))`.  One other thing is my output file size is blowing up (10MB + 30 MB  + 750MB tables = 1.8GB output instead of 790 MB).  I think this is because the #rows (->width) for some id's in some files is much longer.  I'll revise the code here to perform my BULK update differently.

Comment: It's far beyond the scope of the original question. Please, consider to ask a new question.

Comment: Ok, if adding the {} in the case of a null json_agg(filex.*) isn't straight forward I can start a new thread.  Thanks for the help!

Comment: In the end I broke my files up such that only one SQL table was used to generate a given JSON file.  I still used the code above to aggregate by id.  I posted that updated code and also information about a command line script for importing the large JSON files into Elasticsearch via the Bulk API [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33535186/can-jq-perform-aggregation-across-files/33835625#33835625).